# How do I stop Garry's Mod from Printing the Death Message in Console?

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I've been trying for a few days now to make a sort of mystery game with a few friends in Garry's Mod, I managed to get rid of the death notices showing up on the top right of the screen using this [addon](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=194634345) but we found out the deaths are still shown when we open up console. Any way to get rid of them being printed in console?

Comment: Have a look into the code of Trouble in Terrorist Town.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a gamemode, you will probably want to look at the PlayerDeath Hook and override it. If you are just doing an addon, I suggest to use the KillSilent Function on the Player.